# Trend analysis php + postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, statistics, analytics

OK. I have a series of values coming from gps devices that indicate the fuel level in the tanks:

```
80,80,78,79,78,77,72,78,72,78,77,76,75,74,34,33,33,33,32,32,32,
31,31,31,115,115,115,114,114
```

as you can see there is a normal linear trend from 80 to 74 with the exception of some 72 values which is a linear trend that is fine.

Then fuel drops to 34 and this indicates me a theft. After that consumption is ok as it drops to 31 in a linear way.

Then I have a fuel fill up going from 31 to 115.

If i put this in a graph it is very clear and you can spot immediately what is happening. Supposing I want to do some analysis on this series and try and mathematically identify the spots where there has been theft and refills, what options do I have?

What tools are available in php or postgresql to accomplish this?

I have tried with loops but the results are very inconsistent as I'd have to think of a lot of different scenarios and it is too difficult.

I was thinking of analysing the trends of the values by identifying  the lines that are created by the average value of the series split in parts.

Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: This more like a mathematical problem, not so much as programming.

Comment: True. But was unsure if to post it here or on statistics. Do yo think I should move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Guntram Blohm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3066467/guntram-blohm) idea, you can check it like this:

```
$string = '80,80,78,79,78,77,72,78,72,78,77,76,75,74,34,33,33,33,32,32,32,
31,31,31,115,115,115,114,114';

// Create an array of values. If array is available, no need for this part
$values = explode( ',', $string );

// Calculate the differences between numbers and store them in array for
// later analysis
$average = array();
for( $k=0; $k<count( $values )-1; $k++ ) {
    $average[] = abs( $values[$k+1] - $values[$k] );
}

// Calculate the average difference
$total_average = array_sum( $average ) / count( $average );

// Check for differences that are way above average
$k=0;
foreach( $average as $value ) {
    $k++;
    if ( $value > $total_average * 3 )
        echo '<strong>' . $value . ' <-- suspicious</strong> ['
            . $values[$k-1] . '-><span style="color: #f00; font-weight: bold;">'
            . $values[$k] . '</span>->' . $values[$k+1] . ']</br>';
    else
        echo $value . '</br>';
}
```

And the output:

```
0
2
1
1
1
5
6
6
6
1
1
1
1
40 <-- suspicious [74->34->33]
1
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
84 <-- suspicious [31->115->115]
0
0
1
0
```

Comment: Edited the answer to show where exactly numbers have changed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd calculate the average difference between item (n) and (n+1). This should be somewhere between 0 and 3, considering your series. Then double that value and report all differences that are greater that as "something weird here".  Experience will show if "double that value" makes sense, or "multiply by 1.5" or "multiply by 3" works better.